# Meson build system - change compiler to g++

Tags: c++, meson-build

Here is my **meson.build**

```
project('lab1', 'cpp',
        version: '0.1.5')

executable('lab1', 
           'main.cpp', 
           'Graph.cpp', 
           'Matrix.cpp', 
           'menuUtils.cpp',
           cpp_args : '-Wall'
          )
```

The problem is:

```
Sanity check compile stderr:
c++: error: D:\Programming\?++ programming\Discrete-Math\lab1\builddir\meson-private\sanitycheckcpp.cc: Invalid argument
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

-----

meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler c++ can not compile programs.
```

It seems like meson is trying to compile with Microsoft compiler. I don't want it and I want to change it to g++ which I usually use. After googling I realized I have to change the CXX variable, but how do I do it?

Comment: [How do I do X in Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html)

Comment: @JHBonarius I have read that, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Did you set `CC`? See the first paragraph. _"The CC refers to the compiler for the host platform, that is the compiler used to compile programs that run on the machine we will eventually install the project on."_

Comment: @JHBonarius should I set it in my environment variables?

Comment: Well, I don't know. I don't know your system, your setup, your backend, your intention, etc. There is no general right answer, it is specific. I think the documentation on that site is very good (e.g.[Running Meson](https://mesonbuild.com/Running-Meson.html)). You should read it and follow the steps.

Comment: btw CC stands for C compiler, I should use CXX instead https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-tables.html#compiler-and-linker-selection-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to change the compiler to the g++ I have added a new environment variable `CXX` with the value `g++`. On Windows OS, just search `Edit the system environment variables` and than click on `Environment Variables`. [image: system environment variables]

Then set the `CXX` to the appropriate value.
[image: user variable]

Now the CXX is set.

My problem was:

```
Sanity check compile stderr:
g++: error: D:\Programming\?PP_programming\Discrete-Math\lab1\builddir\meson-private\sanitycheckcpp.cc: Invalid argument
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

As far as you can see there is a '?' symbol in the path. Originally my path looks like this:
[image: my folder]

So meson somehow changes the 'C' letter to the '?' symbol. That caused a problem. To fix this problem, just rename the folder.